# Did the Talmidim of Rebbi Akiva die by joining the rebellion with Bar Kochva?

Tags: history, death, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, lag-ba-omer, bar-kochba

I have heard from an Israeli friend of mine that some maintain that the Talmidim of Rebbi Akiva zs'l didn't all die in a plague, but rather they were killed by Roman soldiers because they had participated in the Bar Kochva rebellion. And apparently the current view of their death by plague developed from censored works of the Medieval times. Is there an validity to this claim?

Comment: personally haven't heard of this claim until recently

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/is-there-any-evidence-that-rabbi-akivas-students-fought-alongside-bar-kochba?r=SearchResults